What has been modified in the core of TeX or LaTeX that creates a bug in the xlop package?
Normally the first operand 521 should display _2_ but it displays 52_ and the second operand 177 should display _7_ but it displays 17_.  This xlop package didn't have this bug until 6 months ago.
However, it was last updated by the author on 12 November 2020. So the bug comes from the heart of TeX or LaTeX since this package is written entirely in TeX if I'm not mistaken.
What is used in this package that has been modified in the core of TeX or LateX?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{xlop} 
\opset{decimalsepsymbol={,}}
\newcommand\hole[1]{\texttt{\_}}

\begin{document}

\opadd[carrystyle=\color{white},
operandstyle.1.1=\hole,
operandstyle.1.­3=\hole,%<-----wrong 
operandstyle.2.1=\hole,
operandstyle.2.­3=\hole,%<-----wrong
resultstyle.2=\hole,
resultstyle.3=\hole]%<---good
{521}{177}

\end{document}



I tested on overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/read/dnnssgdkgrtm#06ea75 your document produces 5 2 _ // 1 7 _ // _ _ 8  in every texlive between 2014 and 2024.

How do you test with a 2020 version? I can't find the option on overleaf.

you can switch the version in the menu, below the drop down where you switch the engine.

main left sidebar menu has a dropdown choice to pick a texlive year you can go back as far as 2014

I tried on my machine; the output is the same with versions 0.25, 0.26 and 0.28 of the xlop package.

you have a soft hyphen before the 3 in your code. when I remove that I get _2_ _7_  from your example.

@UlrikeFischer becoming an expert in soft hyphens, I see :-)

@UlrikeFischer I should have noticed that (as emacs is showing it in red...)

@DavidCarlisle for me they looked like a minus, I was only wondering what they mean and then realized that they are not in the original post.

@DavidCarlisle & @UlrikeFischer Same here. I didn't recognized the red color, but was astonished about using -3. Then I've seen, that TeX.SX doesn't show the - and had to think about how to explain it.

@cabohah xlop provides positive and negative parameters. This makes it possible to distinguish between digits in the integer part (positive) and those in the decimal part (negative). The -3 parameter indicates the position of the third digit after the decimal point (thousandths). Parameter 3 indicates the position of the third digit (hundreds).

@AndréC But there aren't decimals in your example and IMHO using -3 wouldn't make sense for what you want … In other words: That was exactly why I was astonished about the -3.

Yes, there wasn't one and xlop in this case doesn't signal that a parameter is being used on a non-existent number, which is why I didn't understand this error at all!

There are invisible - (soft hyphens) in your code. After copy&paste I can see in emacs:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{xlop} 
\opset{decimalsepsymbol={,}}
\newcommand\hole[1]{\texttt{\_}}

\begin{document}

\opadd[carrystyle=\color{white},
operandstyle.1.1=\hole,
operandstyle.1.-3=\hole,%<-----wrong 
operandstyle.2.1=\hole,
operandstyle.2.-3=\hole,%<-----wrong
resultstyle.2=\hole,
resultstyle.3=\hole]%<---good
{521}{177}

\end{document}

After removing the invisible -:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{xlop} 
\opset{decimalsepsymbol={,}}
\newcommand\hole[1]{\texttt{\_}}

\begin{document}

\opadd[carrystyle=\color{white},
operandstyle.1.1=\hole,
operandstyle.1.3=\hole,%<-----corrected
operandstyle.2.1=\hole,
operandstyle.2.3=\hole,%<-----corrected
resultstyle.2=\hole,
resultstyle.3=\hole]%<---good
{521}{177}

\end{document}

I get the expected result:


Great! But how do you see an invisible character?

@AndréC As already told in the answer: emacs shows them (in red, but they are too thin to recognize the different color).

@AndréC they also show as red in overleaf (see the link in the comment under your question)

@DavidCarlisle Thanks, I can see that!
